# Stylecop: Source Control the CustomDictionary.xml dictionary?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resharper, stylecop

I want to place a customdictionary.xml file inside my solution directory and have it source controlled so other developers can also take advantage of this. According to [this StyleCop link](http://www.stylecop.com/docs/SA1650.html) I have to place it next to the stylecop.dll which is under program files.

It also talks about Settings.StyleCop file, which I don't seem to have. Is this per project or per solution ?

The file also talks about a custom.dic, is this different to the customdictionary.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the StyleCop settings editor, you can create a `Settings.StyleCop` file which indicates exactly which rules you want to evaluate for your project/solution.  If you open the Spelling tab of the settings editor, there is a section where you can specify one or more folders where StyleCop will try and find additional CustomDictionary.xml files (you may need to resize the window to see this part)

Comment: Thanks, i found it .. right clicking on a project gives me Stylecop settings, but right clicking on the solution doesn't, is it only project based ? Also the directories that i need to enter are relative to where the settings file is ??

Comment: StyleCop will look up the folder hierarchy and find any StyleCop.Settings files.  So if you put it in your Solution directory (and all your projects are subfolders), it should work.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I have it working but unfortunately I had to create a stylecop.settings in each project... putting it in the solutions dir seemed to disable stylecop inside vs.... strange... but it works now .. thanks