# StyleCop Dictionary relative path

Tags: stylecop

I am having a problem with StyleCop that is most probably a stupid little thing but I cannot manage to correct it and it is driving me crazy because it is making me loose so much time. I hope you can help me.

The problem is the following one: I am working on a large project along with some coworkers, so the code is controlled with Subversion and it is arranged in a tree-like folder hierarchy. We are using StyleCop with this project, and we want to apply the same settings and the same dictionary to all the source code files.

In order to do this, I have placed the settings file in a root directory so the compiler can access it when it is compiling any source code file of the project, as it is specified [here](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sharing%20StyleCop%20Settings%20Across%20Projects&referringTitle=Documentation).

But my troubles are about the dictionary. I want the dictionary file to be placed in the same directory as the setting files, so it is version controlled too. The thing is that in theory, according to [this](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/discussions/397593), I can specify a path relative to the location of the settings file, and the dictionary will be searched there.

So, I just want to tell StyleCop to search for the dictionary in the same folder where the setting files itself is! But I cannot seem to write the relative path that means "this current folder". I have tried really a lot of things: ., ".", $., $(.), ./, .\, %.%...
In the setting files, which is actually an XML file, it looks like this:

```
<StyleCopSettings Version="105">
  <GlobalSettings>
    <CollectionProperty Name="DictionaryFolders">
      <Value>%.%</Value> <!-- Relative paths here-->
      <Value>.</Value>
      <Value>./</Value>
      <Value>.\</Value>
      <!-- etc -->
    </CollectionProperty>
  </GlobalSettings>
...
```

But none of these syntaxis work. In fact many of them make the compiler report a warning that it is not able to parse the XML settings file.

What am I missing? What does the correct syntaxis look like? Or am I doing anything else wrong?

I hope I have made my point clear, and I'd really appreciate some help.

Regards,
Alicia.

**EDIT:**

I finally managed to solve this from a different point of view. Instead of using dictionaries placed in the same folder as the setting file, I added the words that I needed in the setting file itself, like this:

```
<StyleCopSettings Version="105">
  <GlobalSettings>
    <CollectionProperty Name="RecognizedWords">
      <Value>aa</Value>
      <Value>aspx</Value>
      <Value>clk</Value>
      <Value>dll</Value>
      <!-- etc -->
    </CollectionProperty>
  </GlobalSettings>
...
```

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917055/stylecop-source-control-the-customdictionary-xml-dictionary

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
<GlobalSettings>
<CollectionProperty Name="DictionaryFolders">
  <Value><![CDATA[\]]></Value>
</CollectionProperty>
</GlobalSettings>
```

Hint: I came to this conclusion because when I add ".." to the DictionaryFolders property, I get a NullReferenceException in class StyleCop.Utils.MakeAbsolutePath. So it looks as though the StyleCop developers just did not develop their MakeAbsolutePath method in a defensive way and they expect a leading "\".

Comment: I tried this but didn't work for me... I'm sticking to my solution. Still thank you.